# How could i set yesterday value as default value for a numeric parameter in datastage?

Tags: datastage

I have a numeric datatype parameter in Datastage.

```
*parameter name: VAR_ETL_DATE 
*format:YYYYMMDD
*ex:20210612
```

How could i set yesterday value as default value for this parameter?
Format:YYYYMMDD (numeric)

```
*Example: Today:20210824 
*When i run a job including VAR_ETL_PARAMETER with default value, The job should run with yesterday value(20210823)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set it in a static sense, because the date of yesterday is a moving target. The best you could do would be to set it in a controlling sequence job that invokes your job.
Use any of the date offset functions to set the value. For example you could use `Date() - 1` as the generating expression directly in the Job activity in your sequence.

Comment: could you send a link for this method?  @RayWurlod

Comment: There is no link for this method.  I described what you need to do.  No-one has published this particular solution.  DataStage development is sometimes a creative activity.